# Double Improper Integral change of variable mistake.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\int \int \frac{2x^{2}+y^{2}}{1+(2x^{2}+y^{2})^{4}} dxdy$

$D=R^{2}$

Am going to prove that this improper integral converge and calculate its value.

Change of variable (mine)  : $\sqrt{2}x = rcos\alpha $

$ y = rsin\alpha $

Books (change of variable)  :

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x = rcos\alpha $

$ y = rsin\alpha $

Who is right ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please format the question to make it readable?

Comment: I can't get the integrand up ,I copied the formula and changed it to fit my problem.

Comment: You're unlikely to get any answers without a legible question.  If you can't figure out the LaTeX code, use ASCII art, write it out in words, or attach an image.

Comment: I will do that , thanks alot.

Comment: Better, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that the expression $2x^2+y^2$ annoys the integrals badly, so we'd better do something about it. As following:

[image]

what you take is a bit useful than other one, however; you may have what the book had already suggested for $x$ and $y$.